# Warning: .NETStandard.2.0.0.0 Library cannot be imported again

Tags: .net, warnings, compiler-warnings, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm getting this annoying warning message.

"{your path}\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.0\build\NETStandard.Library.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "{your project path}". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. Data...(See my own answer below)

Comment: Did you try to install `NETStandard.Library` 2.0.0 into a "classic" .NET Framework project? That should not be done / necessary..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching my code I finally figured out why VS shows a warning. In the Error list next to the warning look for the Project Name. Unload the project and edit the .csproj file and look for the below references. You'll notice that there are multiple rows with slight variations. Delete these ones and leave the other untouched. Save and reload and the warnings disappeared.

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.0\build\NETStandard.Library.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.0\build\NETStandard.Library.targets'))" />

<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets'))" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the warning message I was getting in Visual Studio 2017

> Warning       "C:[your_path]\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library.netframework\2.0.0-preview2-25405-01\build\NETStandard.Library.NETFramework.common.targets"
>   cannot be imported again. It was already imported at
>   "C:[your_path_2\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library.netframework\2.0.0-preview2-25405-01\build\net461\NETStandard.Library.NETFramework.targets
>   (10,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent
>   import will be ignored.

I was referencing a pre-release version of NETStandard. Replacing with the latest stable version using NuGet manager has resolved the issue.

Before

> ```
> <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library.NETFramework" Version="2.0.0-preview2-25405-01" />
> ```

After

> ```
> <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.1" />
> ```